# The String 'Head' does not represent a revision number

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I'm using Git. I made some changes to a branch that I created and then I committed some changes. But now, when I try to commit code, I get the following message:

> Warning: not all local changes may be shown due to an error: The
>   string 'HEAD' does not represent a revision number.

Also, when I look into the local changes list in IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.6
the following message appears below the list:

> Error updating changes: The string 'HEAD' does not represent a
>   revision number

I would love to get some help on this. I googled the problem but didn't get anything pointing me on the right direction.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I also got this problem and I resolved it by `git reset` from git bash.

Answer (score 66):

I had this same issue. For me simply quitting IntelliJ and re-opening it solved the problem.

Comment: If only quitting and re-opening would be faster ... :-)

Comment: Works on `AppCode` too

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by upgrading git to a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue.There seemed to be some  issue with my Intellij(2016.3) +git version(2.16.2) that was installed on my machine.
I upgraded to Intellij 2018.3 and it works now.My team mates got it resolved it even by upgrading to 2016.3.8(that actaully downgraded git to 1.95.5!)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using git bash command: `git reset` and then Invalidate Caches/Restart Intellij.