# Warning not all local changes may be shown due to an error

Tags: git

I'm using `Git` with `PhpStorm`. When I try to commit code I get the following message:

> Warning: not all local changes may be shown due to an error: The
>   string 'HEAD' does not represent a revision number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The String 'Head' does not represent a revision number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407664/the-string-head-does-not-represent-a-revision-number)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try to perform `git reset` in git console

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem on Android Studio, just open the VCS tab and click the refresh icon as shown below
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using WebStorm 2019.1
just closing and opening again worked for me.

Comment: Works for me. I'm using Intellij 2018.

Answer (score 0):

Running WebStorm with elevated permissions helped in my case.